# JsonConvert Deserialize Avro file got "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: O. Path '', line 0, position 0." Error

Tags: c#, serialization, avro

I am work on a C# project needs to read data from a .avro file from google cloud bucket. However, when I using Newtonsoft.Json to Deserialize an object using:
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()));`
It gives me the error : **"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: O. Path '', line 0, position 0."**. I guess there must some format issue with my .avro file, but after I uploaded to a [avro viewer](https://dataformat.net/avro/schema-viewer) it completely fine and able to convert to json format well. After debugging, I got the value inside JsonConvert.cs file, `public static object? DeserializeObject(string value, Type? type, JsonSerializerSettings? settings)` function, the string value some showslike this:

```
Obj avro.codec null avro.schema� "{"
type ": "
record ", "
name ": "
NetworkOptimizationPlan ", "
fields ": [{"
name ": "...
__fastavro_parsed ": true}���|O;��3_��,5�]P��   ��� �I@��8��8X@��@$��S�K
```

My code is here:

```
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   Uri fileLink = new Uri(gcsLocation);
   var path = String.Join("", fileLink.Segments, 2, fileLink.Segments.Length - 2);
   await _storageClient.DownloadObjectAsync(_bucketName, path, stream);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()));
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code or better way for deserialize avro file using c#? Thank you so much!

Comment: Avro specifies two serialization encodings: binary and JSON. Most applications will use the binary encoding, as it is smaller and faster.Please make sure the  type of serialization encodings.

Comment: Hi @Infosunny thank you so much for the hint. I am new to .avro. Could you please give me more details, like how to use the binary encoding? I tried to use Avro.File package like this: return DataFileReader<T>.OpenReader(stream).Next(); but still got the error : "Not a valid data file!" thank you so much